# Easiest way to create a nested list from flat data

Tags: c#, algorithm

Assume I have the following information in a flat format, for example a list of objects:

```
List<Line> lines = new List<Line>
                                   {
                                       new Line{Id = 1, Level = 0},
                                       new Line{Id = 2, Level = 1},
                                       new Line{Id = 3, Level = 1},
                                       new Line{Id = 4, Level = 2},
                                       new Line{Id = 5, Level = 2},
                                       new Line{Id = 6, Level = 1},
                                       new Line{Id = 7, Level = 1},
                                       new Line{Id = 8, Level = 2},
                                       new Line{Id = 9, Level = 1}
                                   };
```

Each object has an id and a level. What I want to end up with a nested list. For this I have a class which can have a list of children, based on the level.

```
public class NestedLine
    {
        public int Id;
        public List<NestedLine> Children = new List<NestedLine>();
    }
```

What's the easiest way to convert that flat list into a nested list?

EDIT: The only information on how to construct the list is the order of the lines and the level. This should be the result:

```
1
--2
--3
  --4
  --5
--6
--7
  --8
--9
```

Comment: I believe there's some inconsistency with the description of the desired output. Can you please double check that? I didn't quite understand how from the input flat list you can infer which parent a child belongs to.

Comment: I removed the description and replaced it with a diagram. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt.

Calling code

```
List<Line> lines = new List<Line>
                           {
                               new Line{Id = 1, Level = 0},
                               new Line{Id = 2, Level = 1},
                               new Line{Id = 3, Level = 1},
                               new Line{Id = 4, Level = 2},
                               new Line{Id = 5, Level = 2},
                               new Line{Id = 6, Level = 1},
                               new Line{Id = 7, Level = 1},
                               new Line{Id = 8, Level = 2},
                               new Line{Id = 9, Level = 1}
                           };

NestedLine nestedLine = Recusrsive(lines, 0);
```

Recursive Method

```
private NestedLine Recusrsive(List<Line> lines, int listPos)
{
    NestedLine retVal = new NestedLine();
    Line line = lines[listPos];

    retVal.Id = line.Id;

    for (int iItem = listPos + 1; iItem < lines.Count; iItem++)
        if (lines[iItem].Level == line.Level + 1)
            retVal.Children.Add(Recusrsive(lines, iItem));
        else if (lines[iItem].Level <= line.Level) return retVal;

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: what value should i pass in `int listPos`

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a little more information here? This looks to me like you are really dealing with a tree structure:
 
1
-> 2
 
-> 3
 
-> -> 4
 
-> -> 5
 
-> 6
 
-> 7
 
-> -> 8
 
-> 9

am i correct? and if so, what is the rule for determining the parent of the lower level nodes?

The first thing that comes to mind is to use a recursive constructor for your NestedLine class:

public NestedLine(List lines)

Comment: Yes that's it. The rule is simple the order of the list together with the level number.

Comment: holy cow! the SO editor is killing me this morning! basically, I would start with a recursive constructor for NestedLine. Assume the first element of the collection is the node being constructed, then trim off the first node, look at the rest of the collection, and pass it into new NestedLine objects that are then added to the current NestedLine object.  I'll write up a little code sample and push it up in a bit.

Comment: astander's answer, above looks about like what I was trying to get at.  i would have moved this into the a constructor of NestedLine, but a static method would work just as well - i would give him the vote.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack to keep track what was the last item added at each level, pushing and popping as you go along:

```
var stack = new Stack<NestedLine>();
foreach (var line : lines) {
    while (stack.Count > line.Level) {
        // Pop items until the top element is one up from current level
        stack.Pop()
    }
    var child = new NestedLine{Id = line.Id};
    if (stack.Count > 0) {
        // if there is a parent, add the child to its children
        stack.Peek().Children.Add(child);
    }
    // add current line as the deepest item
    stack.Push(child);
}
NestedLine root;
while (stack.Count) {
    root = stack.Pop();
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't actually done much C# programming so this might contain some trivial errors.